# angular2 html does not always load

Tags: html, css, angular, text, loading

I am working with angular and I am having the issue that when my page loads, some of my text just does not display at all. Only after resizing the window makes it appear or , after refreshing a few times. It also does this with button text but in this example with the `<b>` tags. Below are two images, the first one is the one when the text does not laod, the second one is when i resize the window and the third one if I put ? in front of each value in the methods

Thanks for helping!

[image: Image with no text]

[image: Image with text on resize]

[image: Update]

html code:

```
<div id="title">
  <span>Stagevoorstellen</span>
</div>
  <div class="dropdowns">
    <div id="one">
      <b>Status voorstel</b>
      <select #selectedStatus class="form-control" (change)="checkStatus(selectedStatus.value)">
        <option value="ToApprove">Nog te keuren</option>
        <option value="Rejected">Afgekeurd</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <div>
        <b>Afstudeerrichting</b>
        <select #selectedSpecialisation class="form-control" (change)="checkSpecialisation(selectedSpecialisation.value)">
          <option value="EVERYTHING">Alles</option>
          <option value="AON">Applicatieontwikkeling</option>
          <option value="SWM">Softwaremanagement</option>
          <option value="SNB">Systemen en netwerkbeheer</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      <div>
        <b>Reviewer</b>
        <select #reviewerYesOrNo class="form-control" (change)="checkReviewerForNull(reviewerYesOrNo.value)">
          <option value="notAssigned">Niet toegekend</option>
          <option value="assigned">Toegekend</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : add ? mark before each .value

```
<div id="title">
  <span>Stagevoorstellen</span>
</div>
  <div class="dropdowns">
    <div id="one">
      <b>Status voorstel</b>
      <select #selectedStatus class="form-control" (change)="checkStatus(selectedStatus?.value)">
        <option value="ToApprove">Nog te keuren</option>
        <option value="Rejected">Afgekeurd</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <div>
        <b>Afstudeerrichting</b>
        <select #selectedSpecialisation class="form-control" (change)="checkSpecialisation(selectedSpecialisation?.value)">
          <option value="EVERYTHING">Alles</option>
          <option value="AON">Applicatieontwikkeling</option>
          <option value="SWM">Softwaremanagement</option>
          <option value="SNB">Systemen en netwerkbeheer</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      <div>
        <b>Reviewer</b>
        <select #reviewerYesOrNo class="form-control" (change)="checkReviewerForNull(reviewerYesOrNo?.value)">
          <option value="notAssigned">Niet toegekend</option>
          <option value="assigned">Toegekend</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It just changes everything to image 3, removing the other text but loading the text I needed

Comment: can you post your compomnent and your module?